# QEMU VM using virtio drivers without kernel support / module on host?

Tags: qemu, virtio

I was trying to verify that my Win 8.1 VM running in QEMU is getting the full VirtIO benefit for the disk (raw image format) and for the network card. I read [this related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148055/how-to-check-if-virtio-storage-access-is-in-use) and accessed the QEMU human monitor interface and found that it shows:

```
bus:  virtio-bus
    type virtio-pci-bus
    dev: virtio-blk-device, id ""
         drive = "virtio0"
....
bus:  virtio-bus
    type virtio-pci-bus
    dev: virtio-net-device, id ""
```

This makes it appear to be using VirtIO as does the fact that the Windows Device Manager shows Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device and Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter.  However, when I run lsmod on my linux host it does not show any virtio modules loaded and when I check my virtio kernel configuration it doesn't show virtio, virtio_net or virtio_blk built in:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -i virtio
CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=m
CONFIG_SCSI_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_NET=m
CONFIG_CAIF_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_CONSOLE=m
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_DRM_VIRTIO_GPU=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO=m
# Virtio drivers
CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_PCI_LEGACY=y
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BALLOON=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_INPUT=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_MMIO=m
CONFIG_VIRTIO_MMIO_CMDLINE_DEVICES=y
```

I run my VM with a command like:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp cores=2,threads=1 -drive file=filename.raw,index=0,media=disk,if=virtio,cache=none,format=raw -net nic,model=virtio,macaddr=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -net bridge,br=br0 -m 4096 -localtime
```

What am I missing here? Could it be that it's working via pci_virtio_legacy support built in to the kernel? If so, would it be faster to use the other variation and if so do I just make sure to load the virtio, virtio_net and virtio_blk modules before starting the VM?

Answer (score 3):

The virtio *backend* is in qemu itself, not in the host kernel. qemu is taking packets from the guest virtio *frontend* network driver and sending them to the bridge device you requested.

In the host kernel you can have *vhost* drivers to optimise part of the backend function, namely passing the data packets.

See [this blog post](http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/09/qemu-internals-vhost-architecture.html).